# Java regex pattern doesn't works when under Linux (Amazon Beanstalk)

Tags: java, regex, linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java regex pattern that works **perfectly under Tomcat7 in Mac OSX**, but **under Amazon Linux (used on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk) it doesn't match never**.

Here is the pattern:

```
(\d\.)(([^\d\s])([a-z/\s]*))
```

And here is some example of text:

```
  1.AAAA/BBBBBB
```

Here is the java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    //....
}
```

I can't understand what are the platform differences on this. Somebody?

**Edited**

More information: The same .war file, under my Windows, Mac OS platform works perfectly, but in Amazon Beanstalk and Ubuntu Linux no.
I think @study was right, maybe is because the OpenJDK, but I'm under windows now and I can't test it at this moment.

This is the code to test it: 
https://gist.github.com/edpichler/6766187

Comment: I'm not sure, but usually backslashes have to be escaped in Java. Have you tried: `(\\d\\.)(([^\\d\\s])([a-z/\\s]*))`?

Comment: Yes! Sure! The java regex application is working on local tomcat.

Comment: How exactly you're using this regex?

Comment: I edited and added the code.

Comment: Is the input in both cases identical?

Comment: Please attach the test case: a runnable main with the regex and the input.

Comment: I'll test under linux in a virtual machine soon. The only Linux I tested is of the production Amazon AWS

Comment: I'll attach more details soon, I need to go and solve a problem in the next hours.

Comment: I just attached more details. I can't test it on OpenJDK at this moment, and I have not discovered what is the problem till now. Here is the java test class. https://gist.github.com/edpichler/6766187

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Tomcat version will cause different result, so the only difference is JRE version.

In elastic beanstalk tomcat 7 x64, you are using OpenJDK 1.6.0_24

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-121-5-162 ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (amazon-52.1.11.4.46.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

In OS X 10.8.5 (with OS X 2013-004 & 10.6 Update), you are using Oracle JDK 1.6.0_51

```
server:bin study$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. But what is the difference in the regex when change vm?

Comment: Had you get similar problem in OpenJDK? I added more information in the question.

Comment: Hi @EdPichler, I have posted test result in your gist comment. It worked correctly.

Comment: Hi @study, I just tested on Ubuntu with OpenJDK it doesn't worked.

Comment: Hi @EdPichler, it worked correctly on my Amazon Ubuntu 12.04.02 x64 EC2 instance.
I have attached test result in your gist comment.

Comment: I'll do more tests. This methods inside the a war file on Tomcat (linux, tomcat7, openjdk7), the test did not pass. I think the problem is the "[^\d\s]" declaration on linux.